# Breeze JS Security and Headers

Tags: security, http, asp.net-web-api, breeze

We have used Breeze in our solution and it is working well.  However, we are now at a place where we need to pass some identifying information as part of the header when we make the WebAPI call.  How is this accomplished with Breeze queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this link should help you;
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/controlling-ajax

In general, you need to configure the internal ajax adapter (probably jQuery) before making a request.